# Arithmetic operation in jmeter Groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I created a script that receives a variable from another sampler.
I put the variable in a new variable (not want to mess with the source).

And I tried to double the result, the problem is that it multiply as a string and not as in math.
The variable is 6, and I wanted to display 12, but it display 6.0 6.0.

Moreover, how can I save the results in a new variable?

```
System.out.println(" Impression Price *2 is:  " + Impression_price*2);
System.out.println(" Impression Price*2  is:  " + (Impression_price.multiply(2.0)));
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast your `args[3]` which is a [String](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html) to a corresponding [numeric type](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-syntax.html#_numbers), for example:

```
def Impression_price = args[3] as float
```

Demo:

[image: JSR223 Numeric Operations]

More information: [Creating JMeter Variables in Java - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-jmeter-variables-in-java-the-ultimate-guide)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert String do double using `Double.parseDouble`, for example:

```
def Impression_price= Double.parseDouble(args[3]);
```

When you log you need to convert back to String using `String.valueOf`, for example:

```
log.info(String.valueOf(Impression_price*2));
```

To put a non String value you need to use `vars.putObject`:

```
vars.putObject("Impression_price_double", Impression_price *2);
```